# For java developers, what is better than Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, lazy-loading

I am unsure if there is a better way to develop database-backed applications in Java, but I thought I would ask.

There is a lot I like about Hibernate, but there are lots of problems too. Most of them are not that big of deal when you have as much experience with it as I have, but I think the biggest problem that I run into is one-size fits all lazy-loading model. Absolutely hate it - there has to be something better out there... no?

The reason I hate the lazy-loading model is that while it's convenient to specify what is lazy and not lazy in the configuration file, there are many parts of an application that would prefer lazy-loading in one area and no lazy loading in another. If you want to satisfy both parts of the program, you need put up with lazy-loading and manually load entities and their children... and their children... and so on. This is just bloat that doesn't do anything to solve the real programming problems - like the features that get the project done.

It seems that the loading strategy that you want to use should be independent of the mapping information, but this is not possible (as far as I know) with hibernate other than writing the loading inside of your java code.

Another problem I have with the lazy-loading is that it's not easily predictable when you are going to have problems. I often don't discover lazyloadexceptions until I deploy my application into Tomcat.

It feels even more bloated when these exceptions occur from frameworks - like by Jackson calling into a collection that hasn't loaded yet. Or maybe Spring is accessing a property I never asked it to, so it throws a LazyInitializationException anyway - for no reason other than that their framework touches all of my bean properties.

Anyway, because I can't discover these problems during integration tests... when I discover them in Tomcat, I often have to shut down tomcat, make the changes, recompile, reload tomcat, relogin to my application, go back to the page I was at to see if it's fixed - this is truly a massive pain. It takes so long to fix one of these errors. I feel like it's just getting in the way of what I am actually doing.

In the end, I just feel that details like this really weigh me down. When I look at my day and ask, "What did I produce today?" - I find problems like this really get in the way of me feeling like I accomplished something.

Of course, I can just turn off lazyloading... but then I get absolutely dreadful performance.

Is there a better way? Something that "just does the right thing", performs well and easier to reason about?

Thanks

Comment: I'd like to add the famous `toString()` lazy load trap as another painful example.   The short answer for me is that if you want the performance and feature set of Hibernate you need to pay for the complexity.  One of the design goals of ORMLite (http://ormlite.com) was to provide decent ORM functionality but with KISS.  Knowing where the db connections were being made was certainly a requirement.  That said, the lazy load support is very basic compared to Hibernate's -- and there is no object caching.  Best of luck.

Comment: Gray, do you have a relationship with ORMLite?  If so, please acknowledge it.

Comment: you've just discovered that when you're mixing two completely orthogonal concepts (namely OO and relational DBs) you're spending your entire coding life doing "plumbing".  Sadly there cannot be anything as simple as you'd wish when you map tables/rows to objects.  You can do a tradeoff and use an ORM a little bit simpler than Hibernate (at the expense of other stuff) but that won't solve the underlying issue. The issue is that *"ORM is the vietnam of software development"* and you're stuck in it.  Even Jeff Atwood agrees: http://bit.ly/agZZ9k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One person already mentioned Open Session in View, which will eliminate most if not all of your lazy loading problems (but it brings its own problems).

Open JPA has something called '[fetch groups](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/ref_guide_fetch.html)'. This is basically a named set of fetch settings that you can set before running queries, etc. You would then select the appropriate fetch strategy before running the query (presumably in your service impl). This way, the fetch plan is separate from the mapping. You can configure as many fetch plans as you have use cases. In one fetch plan, a particular association is lazy, but in another, it is eager / JOIN. Seems awesome.

If you've been coding to the JPA spec instead of native Hibernate, the switch to Open JPA could be easy.

If I'm not mistaken, some work is being done to implement fetch groups in Hibernate, but I'm too lazy to google that right now.

Comment: Wow, that sounds like a really good solution. I have so many nested object graphs... and each part of the application really does need to load them all differently. This sounds like the JPA guys realized this problem and implemented a real solution. The only reason I didn't know about this is because I really was using native Hibernate configuration files. Perhaps I should move this project over to JPA.

Answer (score 3):

First of, this has nothing to do with Hibernate. Pretty much any ORM (certainly any JPA provider) implements lazy loading in a similar fashion.

As far as "would prefer lazy-loading in one area and no lazy loading in another" goes, you can override lazy fetching via HQL [fetch join](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins) if you're using queries. For straight up `session.get()` there's usually no need to do so (Note - see below), you can just let lazy loading do its magic for you. For that to happen you need to ensure your session stays alive until all requests to entity (its properties / collections / etc...) are done, which is typically achieved via [Open Session in View pattern](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessioninView).
Spring has a [corresponding interceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.html) as well.

Note: One case where you have to load all entity's dependencies is when you're going to ship it to a remote system (thus making original session unavailable). This is typically handled by marshaller, though.

Comment: I am already using open session in view pattern with this Spring project. There are still going to be cases where Spring/Jackson and others will cause these exceptions. It's unavailable in 100% of cases :( Also, much of my loads do not use string-based queries... just get() like you mentioned.

Comment: @egervari - for local application with "open session in view" the only case where session becomes "unavailable" is if your entity lives through multiple requests (and, thus, multiple sessions / transactions) _AND_ you don't access "lazy-loaded" attributes until second or later request. Usually this signifies a problem with  application design; in some cases it can be dealt with by manually re-attaching the entity: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-detached

Comment: Errors will happen during asynchronous calls or if properties are called in Jackson. This happens on a routine basis for me.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with others that the notion of *better* is subjective and context-dependent. True alternatives to JPA / Hibernate are:

#### [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org)

It is the most popular SQL templating engine in Java. It externalises SQL statements into XML files, from where they can be loaded by ID or by other means. As a templating engine, MyBatis also supports SQL composition and a slim templating language for loops and branch statements.

#### [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org)

This is a popular SQL DSL allowing for typesafe construction of SQL statements directly in Java. Unlike MyBatis, this library encourages embedding SQL in Java, instead of externalising it. (Disclaimer, I work for the vendor)

#### Other alternatives...

... include SQL-string-centric libraries that ease some of the pain when operating with JDBC directly:

- [JdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-core)
- [Apache DbUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/)
- [JDBI](http://jdbi.org/)
- [sql2o](http://www.sql2o.org/)
- [persism](http://persism.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate and other ORMs are designed to make RDBMSs work with object oriented applications. If you are not forced to use an RDBMS I would simply use an ODBMS.

Many ODBMS support implicit lazy-loading via byte-code enhancement, so it is almost impossible to write code that accesses an object that is not properly loaded. You can usually also specify (per code-path) closures that load objects not one-by-one but in batches, which improves performance.

Some ODBMS are:

- [db4o](http://www.db4o.com) (free, pure Java, but less powerful)
- [Versant](http://www.versant.com/) (powerful, commercial, Java frontend, C/C++ backend)
- [ObjectStore](http://www.objectstore.com) (commercial)
- [Objectivity](http://objectivity.com) (commercial)

ODBMS are sometimes frowned upon, but (in my experience) never by people that have actually used them. I have ODBMS in small and large projects (up to 10TB and 2.000.000.000 objects) and I would never go back to RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about "better" than Hibernate, but if you don't like it there are other alternatives to try:

1. TopLink (similar to Hibernate)
2. iBatis
3. Spring JDBC support (makes JDBC pretty easy, especially if you're already using Spring)

Answer (score 1):

Another ORM library to consider is [www.sormula.org](http://www.sormula.org). It supports relationships but lazy loading is optional. It was designed to be a simple alternative to the world of complex ORM solutions. I am the author.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the classical ODBMS have also implemented the JPA standard like
[Versant](http://www.versant.com). So it is easy to try it out. If you want to know how fast they are have a look into the [Polepos Benchmark](http://www.polepos.org/) which compares different persistence API's with different implementations with different RDBMS/ODBMS. You can also extend the benchmark easily with your own usecases and run them with all the different persistence technologies.